# Github problem loading files > 100MB failed to push some refs to github directory

Tags: git, github, git-refspec

I have few files(csv and ipynb) that I want to upload on my Github.

Git bash terminal

```
git lfs install 
git lfs track file_name.csv
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m ".gitattributes"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Credit-Risk-Analysis.git
git push -u origin master
git add file_name.csv
git commit -m "commit"
git push -u origin master
```

I get error: failed to push some refs to --------(my directory name) as shown in image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works

```
$git init
$git add file_name.csv
$git commit -m 'message'
$git remote add origin 'https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git'
$ git pull --rebase origin master
$ git push origin master
```